# How to make Spring managed beans transactional

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, managed-bean

I'm working with JSF. Recently we decided to exclude service layer from our project, cause this layer in 80% of cases consist only of recalling the same named dao-methods (definelty, I know, that this way is "not true"). So, now we need to make our managed beans layer transactional, and here is the problem: I can make dao-layer transactional, but when I try to move this duty to managegbeans layer, I get an

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

Dao and managedbeans layers are in separated modules, so they have separated **context.xml** files. When i define **tx:annotation-driven** tag in dao's context.xml file, **@Transactional** annotations in classes in dao-module are *"visible"*, but when I try to define this tag in managedbeans context.xml file, none of the **@Transactional** annotations (neiter the dao, nor the managedbeans) are visible, so i get an exception.

Any ideas, how I can correctly configure transactions?

**applicationContext-dao.xml**

```
 <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:/MSSQLDataSource"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.company.project.entity</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.project.dao"/>
```

**applicationContext-web.xml**

```
<context:annotation-config />

//Just because of the service layer is not fully removed, de facto we are using this import only for imort dao-context
<import resource="classpath:/applicationContext-service.xml"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.project"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" proxy-target-class="false"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

Part of **web.xml**

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:/applicationContext-web.xml
        classpath:/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.company.project.util.ServletContextListenerConfig</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

**ServletContextListenerConfig** class:

```
public class ServletContextListenerConfig implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        System.setProperty("org.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO", "false");
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // NOOP
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
After reading a "couple" of articles, I've spoken, that problem may be in double definition beans because of mapping them by different `<context: component-scan>`. In most of articles I've read, this contexts were root context by `contextConfigLocation`  and servlet-context by `DispatcherServlet` , but in my case I haven't got `DispatcherServlet`, but I have `FacesServlet` by `javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet`. So, does Faces Servlet do the same thing and, if yes, how? I don't see any connection between Faces Servlet and my context.xml files.

**UPDATE 2:**
My fault, that I didn't show this code at once.
Here's my controller:

```
@Component
@ViewScoped
public class ProfileBean extends EntityBeanBase<Profile> {

@Autowired
private ProfileDao profileDao;


@Override
@Transactional
protected List<Profile> getInitEntities() {
    return profileDao.getAll();
}

public void profileNameValidator(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (!selectedEntity.getName().equals(value) && profileDao.exists((String) value)) {
        System.out.println("Error validating");
    }
}
```

`EntityBenBase` consist of many-many methods, but now I'm using only `getInitEntities()`, which is abstract in `EnityBeanBase`.

And ProfileDaoImpl:

```
@Repository
public class ProfileDaoImpl extends BaseDao implements ProfileDao {

    @Override
    public List<Profile> getAll() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Profile.class).list();
    }
..........
}
```

BaseDao is simple:

```
public abstract class BaseDao {
    @Autowired
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory;
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you use CDI or Spring. If you chose CDI look at this [delta spike](http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/jpa.html) otherwise [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) than just annotate method with @Transactional annotation and thats it! Or simply call begin transaction and end transaction where you need it (insert, update, delete)

Comment: Your question title implies that you're managing beans by JSF instead of by Spring (i.e. you're using `@ManagedBean` instead of `@Component` or whatever other offered by Spring). Is this true? This does impossibly match the question body.

Comment: @BalusC i tried to remove '@ManagedBean' annotation and left only '@Component', but this not working for me. In general, I just realized, that I  recently used both of them at the same time.

Comment: You seem to have assumed that `ProfileBean` is a view scoped JSF managed bean which is untrue. `ProfileBean` is however, a Spring's "singleton" bean (the default Spring scope comes into play, since you have beans managed by Spring as implied by `Component`. The JSF `@ViewScoped` annotation is completely ignored. Choose either of them - not both).

Comment: @Tiny, thank you for this moment, you are completly right, but it still does not solve my problem.

Comment: That comment was completely irrelevant to the said problem. I paused Spring these days. Therefore, I can say nothing precise but Spring managed transactions (declarative transactions) require some special annotations like `@Service` (`@Repository`). It is therefore, better to do any business logic on the service layer. On the web layer, you are likely to use programmatic transactions only which you may not like.

Comment: In order to use container managed transactions in Java EE, on the other hand, it requires EJBs. Bean managed transactions is the only alternative on the web layer. Not sure, if Spring supports something special to overcome this situation.

Comment: @Tiny To my mind, Spring does not require annotations like `@Service` or `@Repository` for managing transactions, because I tried to put these annotations on my `ProfileBean` and it did not give any effect. By the way, after these results I no longer understand, what's the difference between **service**  and **controllers** layers? When we were using service layer on our project, it was in separated module, exactly the same as controller layer now (and then). We have no **DispatcherServlet**, which could produce competive context. So, what's the difference?:)